# how to calculate the total sum of printed numbers in java

Tags: java, sum

I'm pretty new to Java and programming in general. My teacher gave us an exercise where we have to calculate all even squared numbers from 0 to 100. I did that. The next question is to calculate the total sum of all these numbers. And I don't know how to approach this, to be honest. Here's what I have so far.

```
    public class Blatt4Aufg3 
{
    
    public static void main (String[] args) 
    {
    int i=0;
    while (i < 100)
    {
        i= i+2;
        System.out.println(i*i);
        
    }
    System.exit(0);
}                       
}
```

Comment: How would you calulate a sum in general?

Comment: What is your problem? You are able to calculate the squares. What keeps you from summing them up?

Comment: You may prefer to start with `for (int i=0; i<=100; i+=2) { . . . }`

Comment: @Thomas well i would say sum = i + i ? but i have 100 squared numbers in cmd and i want to the total sum of them. I just dont understand how i tell java i want the sum of these numbers.

Comment: Firstly, thinks about how you should do in basic maths, then try to convert the little algorithm to Java. And it's when you will try to make the java algo that you will see if you well understand how Java works

Comment: Think about it this way: you're a Mafia boss and people are coming to give you their money. You need to know the sum in the end but you don't know how many people it will be or how much they'll give you. So you get an _empty_ book (aka variable) and each time someone gives you money you strike through the current sum ( aks `sum`) in that book and write a new one ( `sum = ...`) which is the old sum + the new amount of money (I'll leave that for you). Now the only twist is, that you square the amount of money each one gives you to get even more ;) (so `money * money`).

Comment: initiialize the sum with 0 and then assign the square to a variable then increment the sum with the square `sum+=square`

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, I will advise you to do logic building on paper. In this case, think about how will you count the sum.

what does `i = i + 2` do. It adds `2` to the previous value of `i` and updates it.

The solution to your problem is: declare a variable which keeps track of the sums so far.

```
public class Blatt4Aufg3 
{
    
    public static void main (String[] args) 
    {
        int sum = 0;
        int i=0;
        while (i < 100)
        {
            i= i+2;
            int square = i*i;
            System.out.println(square);
            sum += square;
            
        }
        System.out.println(sum);
        System.exit(0);
    }                       
}
```

Here I made the variable square to reduce the number of multiplications, ultimately, to make it efficient.

You can also use the `for` loop instead of the `while` loop which enhances the readability.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i += 2) {
    // Write the code here
}
```

Comment: ... *to100* translates to `i <= 100`

Comment: i see ok. code is working and i understand it, thank you. looks like you forgot two semicolons though?

Comment: @fantaghirocco OP used `< 100`

Answer (score 0):

First we need to write the code for squared values within the given range and our task is to calculate the total sum of printed numbers means adding of all the squared values and print its sum.
java code:

```
   import java.util.Scanner;
   public class SumOFPrintedValues
   {
     public static void main(String args[])
     {
      int sq;
      int sum=0;    //Initializing sum value to 0
      Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in());
      System.out.println("Enter the range from 0 to:");
      int n=sc.nextLine();
      for(int i=0;i<n;i+=2)
      {
       sq=i*i;
       System.out.println("the Square values are:"+sq);
       sum=sum+sq;
      }
     System.out.println("The total sum of printed numbers are:"+sum);
    }
   }
```